# What is Mono Behaviour?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting this message multiple times when I try to run my game:

> The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing

For some reason, all my prefabs are missing a script that dictates something called their 'Mono Behaviour':

[image: contextual inspector]

What is the Mono Behaviour component, and what does it do?

How can I fix this error? I can click the little target circle to bring up all my scripts, but that just gives me all of the scripts that I've written:

[image: project assets]

So I don't really know how to replace my missing Mono Behaviour script... Maybe if I knew what it was I could have a clue how to fix it.

I probably moved something. But how can I select the Mono Behaviour script (whatever it is) if the target just shows me my scripts?

**Update**

I've moved some assets in the project window, but not via the OS (Finder/Explorer) so why is this happening?

Also I am told that Mono Behaviour is a script I've applied...

Don't really get this...isn't the script component a reference to a script?

[image: components]

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used Unity, but it used to create **massive** problems if you move or rename files in your project using Finder or Windows Explorer. All changes to Unity files **must be made** using the Unity app.

Comment: Each one of your scripts is a _Mono Behaviour_. That's why they all appear when you click on the circle. You need to re-drag the appropriate script onto each object that has broken references.

Comment: @jahroy Thanks, I've updated my question, could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Scripts in Unity are a subclass of the _MonoBehaviour_ class. If you use C# you have to explicitly extend _MonoBehaviour_ in every script you wish to attach to a _GameObject_. If you use Unity's version of JavaScript (or more appropriately _UnityScript_), this is taken care of automatically by the compiler.

Comment: So if I'm using Javascript I can delete all of my MonoBehaviour components?

Comment: The components which say "Missing(Mono Script)" are just empty containers which could take in one of your script. you lose nothing by deleting them

Comment: It has nothing to do with what language you use, all scripts are mono scripts. You can either delete the broken references or re-link them with one of your scripts (by dragging and dropping a script onto the "_missing (mono script)_" slot. If you don't think a component needs a script attached, then delete the reference.

Comment: @jahroy Okay, but see in my last screen shot. My Health script is associated fine as is my Melee script. Why do I need a Mono Behaviour component?

Comment: Your health script and melee scripts *ARE* mono behaviours. The slot with the missing mono behaviour can be removed. It's _possibly_ there because you moved, renamed, or deleted a script, but there's no way for us to tell. **You can delete the missing mono script slot!**

Comment: @Starker Please read through the documentation of Unity and the many many tutorials that are out there. This is all very basic knowledge that we should not need to explain to you. Google MonoBehaviour and you should find a wealth of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you have a script attached to a component, but then the script has been deleted (or its reference has lost in another way, such as the meta file being modified).

If you don't know which script used to be there, just delete those Mono Behaviour components.

Answer (score 4):

MonoBehaviour is the Base Class of all scripts that you want to attach to a GameObject. I am not sure how you managed to create a MonoBehaviour Component with a script missing. What you normally do is write your script and then just drag it from the project view onto the GameObject you want it attached to.

Comment: He probably moved or renamed a script in Finder (or Explorer)... This is bad.

Comment: just tested some things out, this can also happen when you rename your scripts in the project view but dont rename the class name in the file

Comment: Tom, could you elaborate on Base Class? Are all of my scripts automatically compiled into one class I don't have access to or something? CiscolPPhone says I can delete the Mono Behaviour components. Will a new Base Class i.e mono behaviour component be generated? If not, what is the point of the Mono Behaviour component?